# Can someone help me add a refresh token to my code that calls artist information through a search bar in spotify

Tags: c#, asp.net, spotify, .aspxauth

After researching how to do so I have been unable to get it to work. As of current I have to manually update my authorization token every 3600 seconds. Here is my code I am running through an aspx.cs document.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Task_2
{

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    // Title variables for the table cells.
    const int ALBUM = 0, ARTIST = 1, DATE = 2, TRACKS = 3, POPULARITY = 4;

    // Authorization key ... at the moment needs to be manually reset every 3600 seconds.
    const string token = "BQAdFDzrPcE-_AXGtaOQUrDyGoxsnClCiJahKOWXOpbzt78UwmyVEYCeXfbo6GqYUJrVdcm_Hbz1FZrGpwhZeBxENpFrwp4gd7JlbBFZpy78uY8IXZdRkZH2zbd677QGRBq_EbEY3TvmnUg";



    // Event function that triggers after the search button is hit.
    public void button1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // Search button and actions
        button1.Text = "Search";
        string name = query.Text;
        // Error checking with try/catch
        try
        {

            // sets label1 to not be visible if results are found. *Label1 says "no results are found"
            Label1.Visible = false;
            Label2.Visible = false;

            // ensures that a name is entered
            if (name != null)
            {


                // creates the search request from spotify. Telling it where to call from.
                string search = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + name + "&type=artist";
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(search);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Accept = "application/json";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                // The output of the response stream.
                string output = String.Empty;

                // Gets a response from the request call and stores it into output
                // Notice how I close the response and abort the request. Release is needed for future WebRequests  
                using (var response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        output = stream.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    response.Close();
                }
                request.Abort();

                // Used for the next api request
                // Gets the first id from the output stream.
                string idString = "";
                int index1 = output.IndexOf("id\" : \"");
                if (index1 != -1) idString = output.Substring(index1 + 7, 22);

                // Used to build the table.
                TableRow[] tRow = new TableRow[6];
                TableCell[][] tCell = new TableCell[6][];

                // Builds an empty table
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    tRow[i] = new TableRow();
                    tCell[i] = new TableCell[6];
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        tCell[i][j] = new TableCell();
                        tCell[i][j].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                        tCell[i][j].Text = "";
                        tCell[i][j].Visible = true;
                        tRow[i].Cells.Add(tCell[i][j]);
                    }
                    Table1.Rows.Add(tRow[i]);
                    Table1.Visible = true;
                }

                // Fills in the artist name in the table.
                for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    tCell[i][ARTIST].Text = name;
                }

                // Fills in the header row with titles.
                Table1.Visible = true;
                tCell[0][ALBUM].Text = "Album Name";
                tCell[0][ARTIST].Text = "Artist Name";
                tCell[0][DATE].Text = "Date of Release";
                tCell[0][TRACKS].Text = "Tracks";
                tCell[0][POPULARITY].Text = "Popularity";

                // Creates the albumb search request from spotify using ID from search artist output.
                string id = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/" + idString + "/albums";
                var idRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(id);
                idRequest.Method = "GET";
                idRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                idRequest.Accept = "application/json";
                idRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                // The output of the response stream.
                string output2 = String.Empty;

                // Gets a response from the request call and stores it into output
                using (var response2 = idRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var stream2 = new StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        output2 = stream2.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    response2.Close();
                }
                idRequest.Abort();

                // Array of album names.
                string[] albumName = new string[5];

                // Used for traversing the output stream.
                index1 = 0;
                int endIndex = 0;

                // Fills in the album name column in table1 from the output stream.
                for (int i = 0, startIndex = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    albumName[i] = "";
                    index1 = output2.IndexOf(" \"name\" : \"", startIndex);
                    if (index1 == -1) break;// in case it doesn't find the substring
                    else
                    {
                        // uses index start and stop points to retreive substring
                        // " "name" : "" has 11 characters
                        endIndex = output2.IndexOf("\"", index1 + 11);
                        albumName[i] = output2.Substring(index1 + 11, endIndex - (index1 + 11));

                        // Gets rid of the excessive data that is not relevant to intended search results.
                        // the output includes Artist name and the literal "Various Artists" after " "name" : ""
                        if (albumName[i] != name && albumName[i] != "Various Artists")
                        {
                            tCell[i + 1][ALBUM].Text = albumName[i];
                        }
                        // ensures the loop counter doesn't get wasted on unintended Artist name or "Various Artists"
                        else
                        {
                            i--;
                        }
                    }
                    //starts index pointer to right after the found substring
                    startIndex = index1 + (endIndex - index1);
                }

                // fills in the release date column; can use the same output as previous request response
                // uses the same logic as previous substring search; in hindsight, should have made a function for this :P
                string[] releaseDate = new string[5];
                index1 = 0;
                for (int i = 0, startIndex = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    releaseDate[i] = "";
                    index1 = output2.IndexOf(" \"release_date\" : \"", startIndex);
                    if (index1 == -1) break;
                    else
                    {
                        endIndex = output2.IndexOf("\"", index1 + 19);
                        releaseDate[i] = output2.Substring(index1 + 19, endIndex - (index1 + 19));
                        tCell[i + 1][DATE].Text = releaseDate[i];
                    }
                    startIndex = index1 + (endIndex - index1);
                }

                // again, could have used a similar function as above
                // this stores the first 5 album IDs used for later WebRequests
                string[] albumID = new string[5];
                index1 = 0;
                for (int i = 0, startIndex = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    albumID[i] = "";
                    index1 = output2.IndexOf("https://open.spotify.com/album/", startIndex);
                    if (index1 == -1) break;
                    else
                    {
                        endIndex = output2.IndexOf("\"", index1 + 31);
                        albumID[i] = output2.Substring(index1 + 31, endIndex - (index1 + 31));
                        tCell[i + 1][TRACKS].Text = albumID[i];
                    }
                    startIndex = index1 + (endIndex - index1);
                }


                // I noticed I can easily loop for the remaining columns
                // the following are strings that will be used for the loop
                string albumFiles = ""; // will combine with albumID[] for api request string
                string output3 = ""; // will contain the response of the request
                string[] popNum = new string[5]; // for the popularity column
                string[] tracksNum = new string[5]; // for the tracks column
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    //usual requests as before
                    albumFiles = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/" + albumID[i];
                    var albumRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(albumFiles);
                    albumRequest.Method = "GET";
                    albumRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                    albumRequest.Accept = "application/json";
                    albumRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                    // usual output taken from response as before
                    output3 = String.Empty;
                    using (var response3 = albumRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (var stream3 = new StreamReader(response3.GetResponseStream()))
                        {
                            output3 = stream3.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        response3.Close();
                    }
                    albumRequest.Abort();

                    // fills in the popularity column
                    // I noticed popularity is only given once in the beginning of the output
                    index1 = 0;
                    popNum[i] = "";
                    index1 = output3.IndexOf("\"popularity\" : ");
                    if (index1 == -1) popNum[i] = "-1"; // just in case it wasn't popular?
                    else
                    {
                        // ""popularity" : " has 15 characters
                        endIndex = output3.IndexOf(",", index1 + 15);
                        popNum[i] = output3.Substring(index1 + 15, endIndex - (index1 + 15));
                        tCell[i + 1][POPULARITY].Text = popNum[i];
                    }

                    // fills in the tracks column
                    // I noticed the only "track_number" I needed was the last one, hence the use of LastIndexOf()
                    index1 = 0;
                    tracksNum[i] = "";
                    index1 = output3.LastIndexOf("\"track_number\" : ");
                    if (index1 == -1) tracksNum[i] = "-1";
                    else
                    {
                        endIndex = output3.IndexOf(",", index1 + 17);
                        tracksNum[i] = output3.Substring(index1 + 17, endIndex - (index1 + 17));
                        tCell[i + 1][TRACKS].Text = tracksNum[i];
                    }
                }

            } // end of if (name != null)

        }  // end of try

        // if something goes wrong, like the search query not providing results
        // then the table gets turned off, and the "no results found" label gets turned on
        catch { 
            Table1.Visible = false;
            Label1.Text = "Sorry, no results found.";
            Label1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my html document as well. Also in aspx.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Task_2.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Default</title>
    </head>
<body style="background-color: lightgrey">

    <div align="center">
        <h1 id="Title" align="center">Search for an Artist:</h1>
    </div>

    <form id= "Searchbar" runat="server" style="text-align:center">
        <asp:TextBox id="query" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick = "button1Clicked"/>
        <div style="margin-top: 5em">   <asp:Table id = "Table1" runat="server" Visible = "false" BorderStyle = "Solid" BackColor = "WhiteSmoke" ForeColor = "Black" Enabled = "true" HorizontalAlign = "Center"  CellPadding = "2" CellSpacing = "2"/> </div>
        <asp:Label id = "Label1" runat="server" Visible = "false" BorderStyle = "None" BackColor = "LightGray" ForeColor = "Black" Enabled = "true"/>
        <asp:Label id = "Label2" runat="server" Visible = "false" BorderStyle = "None" BackColor = "LightGray" ForeColor = "Black" Enabled = "true"/>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The code works I just need a refresh token so the authorization code will be automatic.

Comment: Where are you getting the original token from?

Comment: @Jaxi I am getting it from https://beta.developer.spotify.com. From the search call

Comment: So you've created your own application and gotten your own tokens? You'll need these to hit their auth endpoint in order to return a new token.

Comment: @jaxi So how do I go about doing this? I have looked at the spotify api refresh token explanation and can not get it implemented within my code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this answer helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35999440 ?

It’s for the iOS SDK, but the auth workflow is the same: you need a server side script to help you refresh the client’s auth token.  Your client needs to call *your* server endpoint, which will call the Spotify endpoint, and then pass the refreshed auth token back to the client.

The linked answer has a link to an example server-side script.

The client will need to get an updated auth token before making a call to the Spotify API if the previously used auth token has expired.

See also https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#supported-authorization-flows , which explains the refresh workflow and why it’s done like that.

https://github.com/kocyigityunus/spotify-token-swap looks like a c# implementation of the necessary server-side script.